# AppleLLVM 9.1.0 with c++17 support? or was it a cmake/env issue？

Tags: c++, cmake

I've been working on os X 10.13 with AppleLLVM 9.1.0(clang-902.0.39.1), and example as follow

```
#include <experimental/optional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class p {
  public:
  T value;
  p(T& t):value(t){}
  p(T const& t):value(t){}
  ~p() = default;
};
template <typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr auto operator+(p<T1> const &lhs, p<T2> const &rhs) noexcept {
  return p<decltype(lhs.value + rhs.value)>(lhs.value + rhs.value);
}
int main(int, char* []) {
  p<int> v1(20);
  p<int> v2(10);
  auto v3 = v1+v2;
  std::cout << v3.value <<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

compiled with

```
c++ -std=c++17 -o test test.cpp
```

it works perfect for I was just trying to use the new feature of return type deduction as referred in [N3638](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html) which proposed a written style as

```
template<typename T> auto f(T t);
```

However, when I was about to use it in my CMake(3.11.1) organized project with several flags show as follow:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -fpermissive -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-O0 -ggdb3")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -ggdb3 -DNDEBUG")
```

it failed to compile telling me "'auto' return without trailing return type; deduced return types are a C++14 extension".
and I've tried the next flag also getting the same result:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++17")
```

It mostly look alike a CMake problem failing at environment set, while I got confused about what CMake flags should I set to enable this new feature? Or was it a compiler-related issue?

Comment: (btw, the combination of "extensions off" and "-fpermissive" does not make sense)

Comment: @MarcGlisse In the Question: CMake 3.11.1

Comment: Can you see the compiler command that cmake is running? If your generator is `make`, you can write `make VERBOSE=1`, if it's `ninja`, you can write `ninja -v` (I think). I don't actually know for other generators

Comment: Works for me on linux with either gcc or clang and cmake-3.10.2 (I get `-std=c++1z`).

Comment: @Justin I've exported the env variable and the compiler set to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++, which links to clang and in the end its version's exactly the one I've described--Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1).

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yep I've checked my ubuntu env with g++7.3.1 and the project compiles just fine--so as I've been confused, was it a compiler issue or cmake one? Due to it works fine in command line, what really upsets me was how should I set the CMake flags...

Comment: @Justin Oh I forgot to provide the most important info: the verbose command tells me it uses -std=gnu++11...

Answer (score 0):

Sry guys.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

works absolutely fine.
The problem was caused by an old version dependency library which used "std::auto_ptr" deprecated in c++11 and removed in c++17 (however still compiles in c++11), hence the CMakeLists was dedicated to c++11 standard.
Problem solved.
And in my ubuntu env, the old version library was updated by apt-get.